# Wrong maximum number of pending suggested edits

Tags: bug, editing

At the moment I'm writing this, I have 5 pending suggested edits, but I can't make any more. The maximum number of pending suggested edits should be 20 on beta sites, [according to the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81701/295232), not 5. Has something been misconfigured? Or does the FAQ need an update?

Comment: Can't reproduce - I went on a retagging spree and was able to submit more than 5 edits at once.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can't be reproduced anymore.

Comment: Could a mod add status norepro

Answer (score -1):

When you say "FAQ", you are referring to the FAQ of Meta Stack Exchange. That FAQ answer doesn't seem to distinguish between "Private Beta" and "Public Beta".

These are the privilege levels for a Private Beta:

[image]

This is what they look like for  Public Beta:

[image]

These these are different between Public and Private Beta sites, it might be the case that the number of allowed pending edits is also different (hence the 20 vs 5).